# Rails devise: user_signed_in? not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this in my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= current_user.email %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %><br />
<%= link_to "Opret", new_user_session_path %><br />
<% end %>
```

But when have signed in as a user: 
I still get the links in view:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %><br />
<%= link_to "Opret", new_user_session_path %><br />
```

Why is the helper not working?

Answer (score 22):

Did you use devise's before action in your controller?

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: what controller should this go in? I used devise and I have 'controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` and also `application_controller.rb`

Comment: It should go in the controller for which the view you are trying to manipulate, you can make do with the if loops in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what is behind the user_signed_in? method, either your login is not working correctly or your method is broken.

Maybe try this, if that doesn't work, I would take a look at whats going wrong with the actual login.

```
<%unless current_user.blank? -%>
signed in
<%else -%>
not signed in
<%end-%>
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are using the right model. For example if your model is member then you should use `member_sign_in` instead of `user_sign_in`.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241322/user-signed-in-always-returns-false) could be a possible explanation.

You might have a pre-existing `current_user` method which stops Devise's `current_user` called within `user_signed_in?` from returning expected values.

Answer (score 1):

If login is working properly, it could be because of some kind of caching going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered exactly the same issue and solved it by doing 
    `$bundle exec rails g devise user` again. My problem was `devise_for users` was somehow missing in the routing file.

Comment: devise_for was missing and hence helpers were not recognized in the application views etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it within an action, make sure you add the colon before:

```
before_action :set_global_variables, if: :user_signed_in?
```

Instead of

```
before_action :set_global_variables, if: user_signed_in?
```