# user_signed_in? always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, janrain, rpx

I have been following these railscasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise &&
http://railscasts.com/episodes/233-engage-with-devise
for user authentication, however whenever I try to see if a user is signed in, the response is always false.

I tried a bunch of things to try remediating this issue. I tried different versions of devise and devise_rpx_connectable. I tried changing settings around in the configuration file. I tried running 'rails generate devise:install' a bunch of times with different gem versions.

The weird thing is that when I change around the RPXNow.api_key to something bogus, I don't get an error, which is unexpected behavior.

Here is the code in my application.html.erb file:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
<% else %>  
    <%= link_to_rpx "Sign in", user_session_url %>
<% end %>
<%= javascript_include_rpx(root_url) %>
```

Here is the code in my user model user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :rpx_connectable

    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    validates :email, :uniqueness => true
    .....other stuff....
end
```

Here is part of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

gem 'devise','2.0.0'
gem 'devise_rpx_connectable'
```

and this gets the devise_rpx_connectable gem version 0.2.2

Here is whats in my initializers/devise.rb file:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"
    config.apply_schema = false
    require 'devise/orm/active_record'
    config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
    config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
    config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
    config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
    config.reconfirmable = true
    config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true
    config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
    config.sign_out_via = :delete
    config.rpx_application_name = "appname"
    RPXNow.api_key = "<any_key_we_want_apparently>"
end
```

And this is in our routes.rb file:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
    root :to => "pages#home"
    match 'users/:id' => "users#index" 
    devise_for :users
end
```

--editted after ply's comment---
I did rails g migration add_rpx_to_users rpx_identifier:string

and ran rake db:migrate on this:

```
class AddRpxToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :users, :rpx_identifier, :string
    end
end
```

If anyone has any thoughts, please share. I have been struggling with this issue all day.

Thank you very much!

Comment: did you remember to add a field to your User model for rpx_identiifer....and then migrate?

Comment: I have the same user_signed_in? always returns false problem. Please help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044080/devise-cant-display-sign-in-or-sign-out-in-rails-view

Answer (score 12):

This might be because you might already be using the current_user method in the application controller. Due to that, the devise will not see its implementation of current_user method and hence it always returns false for its helper methods. Just remove or rename the current_user method which you are using and this solves the problem.

Comment: I wish I could up vote this more, I had my own authentication system and switched to devise and forgot to remove my own curren_user helper causing myself about 2 hours of headaches :(