# Rails devise: user_signed_in? not working #Rails5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I tried to use [Rails devise: user_signed_in? not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003883/rails-devise-user-signed-in-not-working/6004175) but it not worked. I also tried it after in VM Box, even changing the system but it's not working. please see the image [image]. In spite of having signed in, it's showing sgin_in page but not admin page.I'm trying to solve it from 2 days looking for all resources.

I've Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5.1.5

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like when you sign up it takes you to the admin#index view. it has the sign up/sign in links at the top, but the content shows Admin#index...

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: please look at this repo, this is mine https://github.com/TechiePriyaRanjan/PrakirtiPuramHomes.git and one you looked in .gif image is of the friend who helped me in resolving the issue. https://github.com/nezirz/testdevise.git 

this is working fine in his system, but none of the above repo are working in my laptop (Windows 10) and desktop (windows 7)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YLYjE is the output of my friend whose .gif image is posted in this question 

Answer (score 0):

your mapping might be different to user, so user_signed_in? would not work then, it changes according to mapping like #{mapping}_signed_in?

also you are on two different routes

```
users/sign_up
```

and

```
admin/index
```

you need to be consitent there in order for helpers to be working fine

Comment: please check the comments of this question  I tried almost everything I knew 

Comment: i have checked your code, first of all you don't have an admin page, you only have a user model and a pages_controller, I would suggest you go thru Rails tutorials and understand the MVC concept. There is a good video tutorial for devise here http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise